# Accessing li elements by the div class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="listItems">
    <ul>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I do not have the ability to alter this base HTML, but I can make alterations with JavaScript.

This list will appear on multiple pages and will be of varying length, and what I want to do is take the items in the list and remove a certain number of items so that the list will default to having 3 items in it (for example).

As the ul and li items have no class attribute, how do I access the list items from the given div class for the above purpose?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll( '.listItems li' )`

Comment: What exactly do you want to alter, and what do you want to alter it to?

Answer (score 1):

document.querySelectorAll('.listItems ul li');

Comment: Your answer should not be a single line. It should contain some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have use of the `.querySelector function` which expects css selectors as parameter. This one selects all `li` items under `ul` items which direct parent has a class "`listItems`"

```
    let allElems = document.querySelectorAll( '.listItems > ul li');
    for (var i = 0, len = allElems.length; i < len; i++) {
        //work with allElems[i]
    }
```

Comment: `$(this)` is not a jQuery related question :)

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you. I will adjust it to vanillajs.

Comment: I'm mildly amused that you used a vanilla selector, but then wrapped the result anyway :P

Comment: It signals, that I used to often jQuery xd