# How would I get multiple "li" elements under a specific "ul" element and put them into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```html
<div id="a", class="1">
  <div class="2">...</div>
  <ul id="b", class="3">
    <li class="4">...</li>
    <li class="4">...</li>
    <li class="4">...</li>
    <li class="4">...</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="5">...</div>
  <div class="6">...</div>
</div>
```

This is some existing code on the site I'm making my extension for and what I want is I want to create an array with all the li elements. So for example if there was 7 li elements my array would have all 7 inside the array, if there was 5 the array would have 5 li elements.

I had a go of the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075385/accessing-li-elements-by-the-div-class-in-javascript) but the answer by Burak put the 3 div's surrounding the ul into my array and the answer by Antonio put nothing into my array.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use

`document.querySelectorAll('#b li');`

Wich will select all `li` in the element that has `id="b"`

You'll found useful docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll